# Is a C compile-time constant applied the same as a preprocessor define variable after compile time?

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

What I'm asking is does a C const variable defined in such a way that its value is known at compile time:

```
const int num = 3;
int main(){
    int arr[num];
}
```

act in the same way as a preprocessor define:

```
#define num 3
int main(){
    int arr[num];
}
```

In that the compiled code would look like:

```
int main(){
    int arr[3];
}
```

In both cases?

Now there might be a nuance where the code with the const looks more like:

```
const int num = 3;
int main(){
    int arr[3];
}
```

Which would also be acceptable, but you understand what I'm asking, which is whether it needs to reference the const at runtime.

Comment: TLDR:  `const int num = 3;` is not an [integer constant expression](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6) and thus can not be used to declare arrays other than VLAs (which Microsoft never implemented and managed to cajole the C11 committee into making optional)

Comment: No, but C23 will bring a limited version of `constexpr` to C which will muddy the waters a bit more.

Comment: @Ethan, Try coding `const int num1 = 3; const int *ptr1 = &num1;` and `#define num2  3 int *ptr2 = &num2;`. `const int num1` does not always work like `#define num2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://godbolt.org/ to see this - even with `-O0`, the compiler seems to define the constant:

```
a:
        .long   3
```

But then reference it as a literal during calls, like a macro, for both array length and `printf` calls which I tested with:

```
        mov     eax, 3
```

See example here - `a` is 9999 to make it more obvious in the assembly https://godbolt.org/z/o6qvaTrY4

However, when using constant pointers, as in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/x59csqMYE at `-O0`, the compiler starts to reference the constant instead of just using its literal value. At `-O3` though, it goes back to inserting the literal straight into the assembly.

Comment: That's ignoring the most important difference on the language level: `num` is not an integer constant expression with `const int num = 3;` and therefore will cause `arr` to be a VLA (if at all).